# Calculus - function strictly increasing question

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f : D \to\operatorname{Im}(f)$ be strictly increasing (for some $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$).
Prove that the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing.

How do I prove this from the definition of a strictly increasing function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $a,b\in \operatorname{Im}(f)$ with $a<b$. Write thes as images of some domain points, and remember that $f$ is strictly order-preserving so $f$ is a bijection. What would be true if $f^{-1}(a)\geq f^{-1}(b)$?